# Python 3 weird behavior of subprocess.call

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Environment:

```
Windows: 10
Python: 2.7.13 and 3.8.1
default Python launcher: py -3
Default python: 2.7.13

> python -V
> Python 2.7.13

> py -3 -V
> Python 3.8.1
```

launcher.py:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', '-V'])
```

1. Test 1: `py -3 launcher.py`

   > Output: python 3.8.1 (HOW!)
2. Test 2: `py -2 launcher.py`

   > Output: Python 2.7.13

The output should be `Python 2.7.13` only, even the launcher runs under py 3!

note that, adding `shell=True` will work, but the idea is not to use it, and if I ran

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'script_under_py_2.py']) # Will run python 3 with script python 2!
```

Thanks

Adam

Comment: Interesting! When I do this on macOS, I get the correct result: both python2 and python3 show me the same `python -V`.

Comment: Change launcher.py to use `sys.executable` instead of `'python'`. The former is the path to the currently running Python interpreter.

Comment: @martineau  that's the opposite of what the OP wants.  For reasons I can't imagine, he appears to want a launcher that will run under either python 2 or python 3 but which will definitively launch a python 2 subprocess.  So, if launching with `py -3`, he actually wants to guarantee that the target is *not* `sys.executable`

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is due to the inconsistent handling of the `PATH` environment variable when calling `Popen` on Windows and Unix.

Windows creates its sub-processes using [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function. The search path for `CreateProcess` [includes](https://bugs.python.org/msg262399) parent process directory, which may be the reason why you are having different binaries executed.

On Windows, PATH is only considered when `shell=True` is also passed.

You can learn more about the issue here:

- [subprocess PATH semantics and portability](https://bugs.python.org/issue8557) (notice the "needs patch" stage)

Comment: thank you for the reply, it's a good reference you added, it seems there is no yet a clean solution :S.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that `subprocess.call` is failing to honour `os.environ['PATH']` then you could always explicitly search that path for the executable you want to call, and then call it by its absolute path, as follows:

```
# Manually search the operating system's PATH for python[.exe]
import os, sys
ospath = os.environ['PATH'].split(os.path.pathsep)
_, extension = os.path.splitext(sys.executable)
target = 'python' + extension
matches = [os.path.join(directory, target) for directory in ospath]
matches = [match for match in matches if os.path.isfile(match)]
if not matches: raise OSError('{!r} was not found in any PATH directory'.format(target))
python = matches[0]

# Test:
import subprocess
print('I am Python {} and I am calling "{}" -V'.format(sys.version.split()[0], python))
subprocess.call([python, '-V'])
```

Of course, that *won't* do what you want if the `py -3` wrapper works by actually changing the path before launching Python...  I'm not familiar with that wrapper so I don't know whether that will be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wish can do that, it's a good solution if was one script or known input, the problem is in user input, can be "python ...", it seems needs to do extra dirty logic!